# ionic or angular object pass to view issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Here is my home.ts
only issue is that i am not able to access object in home.html like {{detail.ID}}

```
senddata(){
    this.httpClient.get('http://queenstshirtdesigner.com/wp-json/posts/'+this.id,  
    {
        headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.detail = data;
        console.log(data.ID);///this is working
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`detail` is set asynchron. So `detail` is undefined when the template is rendered. Don't set `detail` before and try `detail?.ID` in the template. Then it should be rendered when loading is finished.

Comment: I already declare `detail` on top. how i can implement your solution . please explain me little bit more